# Is it possible to change a the converter of a binding in a trigger in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got the following `TabItem` template where the `TabItem` contains an image whose source depends on the `IsSelected` property.  I accomplish this by binding the `Image.Source` to the `TabItem.Header`, with a `Converter` that converts the header text to a full filename.  (i.e. a header of "awb" will become "images/awb-white.png" or "images/awb-black.png" depending on the converter).

This code works, but it seems to have some unnecessary redundancy.  All I really need to change is the `Image.Source`'s binding's converter; not the whole binding itself.  (The RelativeSource and Path both stay the same).  Is there any way to accomplish this without the redundancy?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:UnselectedImageFilenameConverter x:Key="UnselectedImageFilenameConverter" />
    <local:SelectedImageFilenameConverter x:Key="SelectedImageFilenameConverter" />
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
        <Image x:Name="TabImage" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Header, Converter={StaticResource UnselectedImageFilenameConverter}}" Stretch="None"/>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="TabImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Header, Converter={StaticResource SelectedImageFilenameConverter}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="awb" Template="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}">
        <Grid/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="av" Template="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}">
        <Grid/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge that is not possible.

But you could change the way you handle this by creating only one converter but passing both the original value and the selection status via a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx). (The converter would need to be an [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)). Whether that is a good idea is of course questionable...